# What happens if there's a number in front of x to the power of zero?

Tags: calculus

The problem is to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $-\frac{4}{5}$x - $\frac{1}{3}$

I have (1)($-\frac{4}{5})x^0$

Is the answer 1 because of $x^0$ also affecting the number in front? Or is it $-\frac{4}{5}$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you just have
$$
x^0=1
$$ giving
$$
-\frac45\times x^0=-\frac45\times 1
$$ that is

> $$
> -\frac45\times x^0=-\frac45.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

You would treat it as you would any other power. If $x=3$ then $5x^2 = 45$ whereas $(5x)^2 = 225$.